# Cant see DB data if i run an INSERT in the DB (JAVA + HIBERNATE)

Tags: java, spring, database, oracle, hibernate

I searched a lot about this but didnt find anything.

The thing is that if i run an INSERT directly in the database (using SQL Developer), i cant see the results in my app (MVC Java app with SPRING). BUT, if i develope an app to insert data into the DB with hibernate, THEN i can see the data.

```
Instructor tempInstructor = session.get(Instructor.class, theId);
        

        Courses tempCourse1 = new Courses("SPRING");

        System.out.println("Addint courses: "+ tempCourse1.getTitle()+ ", " + 
                                                             tempCourse2.getTitle());
        tempInstructor.add(tempCourse1);
        
        session.save(tempCourse1);
        
        session.getTransaction().commit();
```

What am i missing? I'm doing a simple INSERT, why is not displaying it?

Thanks!

Comment: You have a commit in the code you posted.  Are you committing the change in SQL Developer?

Comment: You can edit your question to include more information.  It still points to the probability that you haven't committed in SQL Developer.

Comment: Oh man, you saved me. Didnt know about the commit in sql, thought that with only the INSERT was enough. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Data modifications (insert, delete, update) made by one session are not visible to any other sessions until they are committed.

Comment: Thank you all. I spent a month searching and i bought a course in udemy just to understand this. Now i can continue with the course normaly. Thanks and have a nice day.